# returned array referencing the same memory spot but returning different values

Tags: flask, jinja2, python-3.7

I'm setting up a basic dynamic web page to display EC2 instance data and I need to be checking and passing arrays with the data inside to display with D3. Im using multiprocess to run the collection in the background.

Running python3.7 and the newest version of Flask.

app.py Code

```
    @app.route('/experiment')
    def experiment():
        type = request.args.get('type')
        resource = request.args.get('resource')
        action = request.args.get('action')
        if 'test' not in session:
            thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=exp.transmitTest)
            session['test'] = 'started'
            thread.start()
        print(f"Looking for Data at {hex(id(exp.getData()))} found {exp.getData()}")
        return render_template('experiment.html',  data=exp.getData(), type=request.args.get('type'), resource=request.args.get('resource'), action=request.args.get('action'))
```

Backend Code

```
    def transmitTest(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.data.append(random.randint(0,100))
            time.sleep(4)
            print(f"Data: {self.data} at {hex(id(self.data))}")

    def getData(self):
        return self.data
```

My JS scheduler runs '/experiment' every 5 seconds. The print statements show that the array im writing to and getting from the getter are at the same memory space, but one is empty and the other has the data. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

so I figured it out. When calling object methods in processes in flask python creates copies of the objects and then differentiates between the two copies even if they do take up the same memory space. I needed to add a backend queue through redisqueue (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) so that I could make asynchronous calls to my backend without disrupting flask's routing.